# $(X \setminus F) \cap Y = Y \setminus A \Leftrightarrow A = F \cap Y$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}), (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces, where $Y \subset X$ and $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is the subset topology. Let $A \subset Y$. During a proof of something (it's not really important so I won't mention it), a particular comment has thrown me.

> Let $F \subset X$. Then $(X \setminus F) \cap Y = Y \setminus A \Leftrightarrow A = F \cap Y$.

"This is set theoretical and easy to check."

How would I go about proving this? I don't really know where to start (I've tried considering complements of the complements, but I didn't really know what to do with it).

Comment: Try writing out differences $A \setminus B = A \cap B^C$ and use the associativity of $\cap$.

Comment: I suppose $Y \subset X$ (for you to say subset topology)?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Edited, thanks.

Comment: @qaphla What does $B^C$ mean? The complement of $B$ in what?

Comment: Choose some large enough set that all sets that you're working with live in. In the particular statement of your problem, $X$ should be sufficiently large.

Comment: @qaphla For the forward direction, the furthest I can get is $Y \setminus A = Y \cap (X \setminus A) = (X \setminus F) \cap Y = Y \setminus F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write taking $X$ as reference to any complementation $X\setminus F=F^\complement$ and $Y\setminus A=Y\cap A^\complement$ then finally you have that $F^\complement\cap Y=Y\cap A^\complement$.

The last equality can be re-written as $Y\setminus F=Y\setminus A$, then $Y\cap F=Y\cap A$, and cause $A\subset Y$ then finally $Y\cap F=A$.

> The "hidden" double implication is $Y\setminus F=Y\setminus A \iff Y\cap F=Y\cap A$, and this can be proven seeing that $A\setminus B =A\setminus (A\cap B)$

Note: this is not a proof in the more elemental sense i.e. using logic operators and showing that some $x$ belongs to some set $A$. This is just using algebraic manipulations, in the same sense that when you solve any equation, to show the "iff" statement.

Comment: I'm not too sure this actually proves the statement...

Comment: @IrregularUser It does, completely.

Comment: How does it? Could you perhaps be more explicit with which directions you're proving? Because all I'm seeing is the two separate parts being rewritten. Note that I'm not saying that it's wrong, it's just that I'm not understanding what you're doing in it.

Comment: @IrregularUser Im not using "directions" just using well-known algebraic manipulations between sets and definitions of set operators. The only thing I dont write explicitly is the statement that $A\setminus B=A\setminus(A\cap B)$

Comment: If you're not using directions, then how have you prove then statements $\text{thing }1 \implies \text{thing }2$ and $\text{thing }2 \implies \text{thing }1$?

Comment: @IrregularUser because the operator "=" (equality) implies a double logic implication. When you are solving some equation algebraically you are demonstrating it. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28mathematics%29#Logical_formulations). You can divide the proof on "directions", this is good when you have to demonstrate complicated things... but if you can demonstrate it algebraically it generally is faster.

Comment: Now that you've made that clear, I can understand your proof and what its aims were. Could you write a comment on this in your answer? Since this is really what helped me understand your proof.

Answer (score 2):

Write $F = G \sqcup H$ where $\sqcup$ means disjoint union and

$$G = F\cap Y\\H = F\setminus (F\cap Y)$$

Then $X\setminus F = X\setminus (G\sqcup H) = (X\setminus G) \cap (X\setminus H)$.

> Indeed, $x \in X\setminus (G\sqcup H)$ if and only if $x \in X$ and $x \notin G\sqcup Y$, that is, if and only if $x \in X$ and $x \notin G$ and $x \notin H$.

Now, $H \cap Y = \emptyset$, and since $Y\subset X$ we have that $Y \subset X\setminus H$. It follows that $(X\setminus H)\cap Y = Y$. Hence, $(X\setminus F) \cap Y = (X\setminus G) \cap Y$. In other words, that's the set of all $x \in X$ with $x \notin G$ and $x \in Y$. Once again, since $Y \subset X$ this reduces to $x \in Y$ and $x\notin G$, so $$(X\setminus F) \cap Y = Y\setminus G = Y \setminus (F\cap Y)$$

Finally, since $A \subset Y$, we have that $Y \setminus A = Y \setminus (F\cap Y)$ if and only if $A = F\cap Y$, which completes the proof.